# Dynamic Webpage Scraping using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to scrape a dynamically created webpage using Excel VBA. I came across 3 solutions:

1. Internet Explorer in VBA - I cannot use this as my Excel workbook is going to be used by 100s of people and a lot of people nowadays disable Internet Explorer in their system.
2. Selenium basic driver for VBA - Same problem, I cannot ask each and every one of the 100s of users to install the selenium basic driver for VBA and then install chrome driver.
3. XMLHTTP - So I followed this approach but the problem is I am not able to modify the code in a way that it let's the page to load completely.

The Link - https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/CTXS/Earnings/Earnings-Dates

Code -
`
Sub pullData()

```
Dim httpRequest As Object
Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Dim URL As String

URL = "https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/CTXS/Earnings/Earnings-Dates"
With httpRequest
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send
End With
With httpRequest
    While Not .readyState = 4                               '<---------- wait
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
    Wend
    If .Status = 200 Then
        While InStr(1, .responseText, "Updating", 0) > 0    '<---------- wait again
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
        Wend
        Debug.Print (.responseText)
        'continue...
    End If
End With
```

End Sub
`

Information required - Date and Time of Earnings and Next Estimated earnings (Marked in the Screenshot)
[image]

Comment: The URL you gave in your question and the URL in your code is totally different, typo? Response via XMLHTTP has no loading so you don't have to check for `readystate` or wait for it to load because there isn't any.

Comment: @RaymondWu thanks for pointing out the error. I have updated the link in the code part. So, is there any way of waiting for the page to load if I can't use the readystate.

Comment: There is no loading, at all. So you will have to find the data you want  in the response and if you can't find it, you will have to look for the XHR that returns the data. I think for your situation, you are out of luck as the data seems to be encrypted. @Mayank

Comment: Hundreds of people are collaborating on this? Maybe you, or one individual, should do the scraping, and have the results pushed to a centralized data warehouse.

Comment: @ASH I think I misquoted myself. Hundreds of users are not collaborating but this workbook is meant for individual use by hundreds of persons. This excel workbook is supposed to be sold to individual users to help with their stock trading